# Error at `Request.QueryString["ID"]` in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have an Insert method which takes an object with 3 fields as parameter and one of the field is `SiteID` which i already have in 'Querystring["ID"]'

```
public static void ProcessIT(string Xindex, string Yindex)
    {
        SiteLogic SL = new SiteLogic();
        Site ste = SL.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
        Walkable W = new Walkable();
        W.X = Convert.ToInt32(Xindex);
        W.Y = Convert.ToInt32(Yindex);
        W.SiteID = ste.SiteID;
        WalkableLogic wlc = new WalkableLogic();
        wlc.Insert(W);
    }
}
```

now when i try to fetch the ID by `Request.QueryString["ID"]` it shows this error  "an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property 'System.web.UI.Page.Request.get'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code being static method, instead, doesn't have access to Request property, since static methods do not have access to instance members.

Use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` instead of `Request.Url` to make your code more universal.